# Ian McEwan's usage of "must" as a simple past

Tags: modal-verbs, past-vs-present

Reading Ian McEwan's "The Children Act", I found this sentence:

"If Jack, sprawled across from her, seemed absurd in this conversation, then how much more so MUST she appear to him."

Being italophone, I struggled a bit in attributing the appropriate tense value of "must".

Does it have to be interpreted as a simple past?

If that is the case, what might have been McEwan's stylistic reason in not opting for "had to"?

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Vincenzo

Comment: I do not understand why you think that the verb *must appear* is in “the simple past”.  It has a modal and an infinitive. There can be be no distinction of present versus past with *must*, no matter whether it’s used in its deontic sense or its epistemic sense. Could you please edit your question to make clear why you are thinking that *must appear* is in “the simple past”?

Comment: Had the author written: "...she HAD TO appear...", wouldn't it have been better, since the whole sentence is in the past? Again, are we facing an uncommon usage of the modal MUST in the past?

Comment: I don’t see what’s uncommon about something like “He told me he must be at his desk working before sunrise every day of the year.”

Comment: Thank you. I am beginning to understand. So I have this alternative: a) He told me he must leave; b) He told me had to leave. Right?

Comment: No, the second one is missing a piece: *He told me he had to leave.*  Be aware however that *He told me has to leave* is also completely valid — and means something a bit different. The thing is that *must* has no tense, and so it can mean either of those. If you try to apply a Romance sequence-of-tenses rule to a Germanic language that has modals, you are doomed, because it just not map. You are probably trying to translate into Italian and therefore trying to make it fit into an Italian model. But it doesn’t have one, being Germanic.

Comment: oops...yes, I forgot the subject in the second sentence! tchrist, this is very interesting. I really have to change my way of thinking here. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: You will forgive me if I keep on brainstorming about this: a) He says he can do it immediately; b) He said he CAN do it immediately. Are these two sentences both correct? And if one should say "He said he COULD do it immediately", would this be the proof that the modal CAN has the past tense as well? Can we say that MUST is a defective modal that only has one form? Is this related to the fact that MUST is already the past form of MOTAN?

Comment: The *will/would*, *shall/should*, *can/could*, and *may/might* connection between past and present is now tenuous at best, occurring mainly in back-shifting. Many and probably most native speakers no longer perceive those as tense distinctions in other circumstances. For example, *he might do something* is normally just a less probably variant of *he may something* just as *could* is less probably than *can*. However, even were those preserved as opponent tenses, with *must* we have no paired present–past form, and so it must serve as both and either and neither, all simultaneously.

Answer (score 4):

The *must* is used as a modal, so tense distinctions don't apply the same way (so much so that while once it was a past-tense form, it's present is now obsolete and not found in modern English at all).

More to the point, the "appear" is bare infinitive.

It would be more normal to have it as, "…then how much more so must she have appeared to him".

> Does it have to be interpreted as a simple past?

The first clause is simple past, but the second has no tense.

> …what might have been McEwan's stylistic reason…

There's a few reasons why we might switch tense or use none. From that sentence alone we might imagine a change in temporal viewpoint. We can see this more with [a bit more context](http://www.vogue.com/1303653/ian-mcewan-book-the-children-act-excerpt/):

> Then there was age. Not the full withering, not just yet, but its early promise was shining through, just as one might catch in a certain light a glimpse of the adult in a ten-year-old’s face. If Jack, sprawled across from her, seemed absurd in this conversation, then how much more so must she appear to him.

Since she's considering the effects of age, while we're told about how Jack appeared at the time being discussed, she's not going to get younger between the "then" of the story and the "now" of the story-telling. This subtly underlines the fact that "the effects of age" are not going to go away in the future, but rather they will increase. And so to answer whether it should be "interpreted as a simple past", it is something that is in the past **and** outside of it as well.

Another common use for switching tenses in fiction is to switch between past-tense accounts of events and present-tense accounts of thoughts. What McEwan is doing something similar. It gives the thoughts greater immediacy.

It's still a bit of an artistic stretch here, but with someone who deliberately bends the rules of grammar as McEwan does with his heavy use of fragments and heavy ellipsis*, it's far from the greatest stretch you might come across.

But to complete your question…

> what might have been McEwan's stylistic reason in not opting for "had to"

*Had to* can be used in a lot of places where *must* is used. Let us consider:

> If Jack, sprawled across from her, seemed absurd in this conversation, then how much more so must she appear to him.
>
> If Jack, sprawled across from her, seemed absurd in this conversation, then how much more so she had to appear to him.
>
> If Jack, sprawled across from her, seemed absurd in this conversation, then how much more so had she to appear to him. [an alternative "had-to" version]

There are a few differences here:

One is that "have to" for "must" is considered informal to some and some others just wouldn't think of it.

Another is that this is especially so with the must of necessity than the must of obligation; that is many people would not use "had to" with the must of "it must be hot outside" but would of "I must/have to finish this report". (Some would; it's something people disagree on). It's the former meaning of *must* at work here.

Another is that I had to rephrase because while McEwan followed "how much more so" immediately with the *must* I couldn't do that with *had to". I either had to have all of it after *she* or split the *had to*. Splitting is arguably inelegant in itself. The *must* form has a nice pattern; [state described] [must] [another state described]. The *had to* form loses this.

A consequence of that, is that that second description of a state, "…she appear to him" loses its brevity.

I think neither of the two *had to* alternatives have the same impact, even if we allow "had to" in such a case which, as said, many would not.

---

*From near the beginning of the same story:

> Probably a fake. Below it, centered on a round walnut table, a blue vase. No memory of when she last put flowers in it. A Bokhara rug spread on wide polished floorboards.

It works very well, though an English teacher would run out of red ink if they had much of that given to them. Indeed, McEwan breaks the rules very well, but if you don't yet know the rules yet, he's a bad model to follow. There are though Italian writers who do the same thing (I'm pretty sure I can remember Italo Calvino do so, though I only read him in translation, and a long time ago).

Comment: How can *appear* be present tense with a subject of *she*?  It would be marked as *she appear**s***.  It must be observed that modals take infinitives.

Comment: +1@Jon Hanna - yeah, also really enjoyed your manner of teaching this lesson. Found it very interesting and clearly, comprehensively, "broke-down." Thanks.

Comment: @LittleEva thanks, but tchrist is correct that *appear* is bare infinitive, not present tense. There was a case of once one misreads something, one keeps misreading it the same way that led me astray. The gist above applies so I edited to fix. The main difference in my misreading and the correct reading is that a bare infinitive here is much more normal than the present would be.

Comment: @Jon Hanna - the particulars of that give & take with tchrist (obviously, a _giant_) largely eluded me (modals?) as I am grammatically ignorant. I speak/write the language fairly well, I just couldn't tell you how (can you link me to a quick course **For Dummies?**). My affirmation was directed at the consistent _tone_ of your communications here at EL&U, as well as your grammatical facility.

Comment: @LittleEva http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs would be a good starting point, along with links off that page.

Answer (score 3):

MacEwan is using a stylistic advice called [Deep Point of View](http://jordanmccollum.com/2009/07/deep-pov/) to put the reader into the head of his main protagonist. McEwan could have written:

> Fiona thought, "How absurd I must appear to Jack!" (direct speech) or
>   Fiona thought how absurd she must appear to Jack (indirect speech).

But representing his main character's direct internal monologue in this way makes for better writing - although it can be more demanding for the reader.

---

Note: *must* here is being used in its epistemic sense of expressing inference, not in its deontic sense of expressing obligation.

It is uncommon to use *had to* as the past tense of epistemic *must*.

> Why did he say that? - ?He had to be tired. (Much more usual: He must
>   have been tired.)

On this basis, McEwan could have written *then how much more so must she have appeared* to him. But the form he chose puts us even more directly into the present thoughts of his protagonist.

Comment: +1@Shoe - I really enjoyed your manner of communicating that lesson. Excellent instruction, very informative. I occasionally do hear, in casual conversation around the house, statements like, "he _had_ to be tired." It's a colloquialism understood easily in situ.

Answer (score 1):

It's based on this sense of the verb, from [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/must)

> Expressing an opinion about something that is logically very likely:
>   *there must be something wrong.*
>   *you must be tired.*

There's no specific tense expressed by this.

Why did he use this construct? I think the inverted form he used tends to be used less in casual conversation, so it seems more literary or poetic. Casual conversation uses *had to* or *has to*.

Comment: No, *appear* is completely untensed: it is in the infinitive.

Comment: But if you wanted to express that it happened in the past, you'd say _must she have appeared_.

Comment: Even if that were so, there would still be nothing in the past tense in *must have appeared*: you have a modal, an infinitive, and a participle: none of those are tensed forms.  The present tense is *she has* and the past tense is *she had*.

Comment: OK, I've removed the part about the tense.

Comment: Exactly! Had I read: "She must have appeared..." I would have understood. That "She must appear" in the context of a past construct, is really confusing me.